# How master communicates with other nodes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it uses xmlrpc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351594/how-master-communicates-with-other-nodes?/) by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-06**:
@Bobby: I would suggest to read through the [wiki/ROS/Introduction](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction) page, and then follow that up with the [wiki/ROS/Concepts](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts) page and all pages linked from that.

Those pages may answer a lot of your questions.

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-05-06**:
I'm really very sorry I'm beginner to this and I'm finding very difficult in understanding the concepts.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-06**:
You don't need to apologise for anything.

All we ask is that you read those pages, try to understand what they're describing and if/when you have any further questions, you're more than welcome to post your questions here.

What we do ask of you in that case is to *be specific*, explain what you don't understand, *where you read it*, include a link to the page, or section or chapter, and clearly state what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes: http://wiki.ros.org/Master#XMLRPC_API

Please check the wiki, and google a bit. This is within the first three hits for "ROS master node communication"

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1